# ¿Cómo hacer un array estático en JavaScript muy sencillo para un 3 en raya?

Tags: javascript, array

Hay muchos problemas en mi programa, entre ellos:

- La O machaca a la X, es decir, si hay una x el programa lo superpone con una o en el tercer turno y creo que es porque el array casillasDisponibles no es un array estático, **en el tercer turno las posiciones es igual a 15,16,18 cuando siempre deberían de ser del 0-8.**¿Hay alguna forma muy simple de hacerlo?, estoy recién empezando.
- A veces no imprime la O.
- A veces te dice mal si has ganado o perdido.
- A veces el click no lo coge bien y no pinta una x.

```js
//Declaraciones de array

const casillasInterno = {
    relleno: ["v","v","v","v","o","v","v","v","v"],
};

var guardarClicks = [];
var guardarX = [];
var flagClicking = false;
//PRECARGAMOS LAS IMAGENES
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var imagenX = new Image();  //Creamos el objeto imagen
imagenX.src = "./img/x.png";    //Asociamos la ruta de la imagenX
fotoX = '<img src="'+imagenX.src+'" />';

var imagenR = new Image(); 
imagenR.src = "./img/_.png"; 
fotoR = '<img src="'+imagenR.src+'" />';


var imagenO = new Image(); 
imagenO.src = "./img/o.png"; 
fotoO = '<img src="'+imagenO.src+'" />';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.getElementById('casilla4').innerHTML += fotoO;

function ponerImagen(i,foto){
    switch (i) {
        case 0:  
            document.getElementById('casilla0').innerHTML = foto;
            break;
        
        case 1:
            document.getElementById('casilla1').innerHTML = foto; 
            break;

        case 2:
            document.getElementById('casilla2').innerHTML = foto; 
            break;

        case 3:
            document.getElementById('casilla3').innerHTML = foto; 
            break;

        case 4:
            pintaMaquina();
            break;

        case 5:
            document.getElementById('casilla5').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

        case 6:
            document.getElementById('casilla6').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

        case 7:
            document.getElementById('casilla7').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

        case 8:
            document.getElementById('casilla8').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

    }
          
}

function comienzaElJuego(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        
        if (i != 4){  //El 4 es el centro del tablero
            ponerImagen(i,fotoR);
        }
    }

}

function pintarO(i){ //Le pasamos el numero random generado en pintaMaquina
    //Siempre se cumplira la condición hasta que ya no queden posiciones
    if (i >= 0 && i < casillasInterno.relleno.length){ //Si el numero random es mayor o igual a 0 y nRandom es menor a las casillas del primer array
        //Insertamos el caracter o
        casillasInterno.relleno.splice(i,0,"o");
        ponerImagen(i,fotoO);
    }
   
}
function random() {
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * (8 - 0 + 1)) + 0);
    return num;
}

function pintaMaquina(){
    // //Nos cargamos el array antes de salir para que cojamos las posiciones ocupadas del siguiente turno  .
    // casillasDisponibles.relleno.length = 0;
    var casillasDisponibles = [];
    alert("Esta pintando la maquina...");

    for (let i = 0; i < casillasInterno.relleno.length; i++){
        if (casillasInterno.relleno[i] === "v"){//le decimos que si encuentra una v que la guarde en el segundo array según la posición
            casillasDisponibles.splice(i, "v"); //Borramos la v que haya 
            var aleatorio = random(); //Generamos otro numero aleatorio para que donde lo inserte sea distinto y no vaya en orden
            casillasDisponibles.splice(aleatorio, 0, i); //En una posicion aleatoria en un rango del 0-9 le pasamos el numero de dicha posición
        }  
        
    }
    var n = random();
    for (let i = 0; i < casillasDisponibles.length; i++){ //Si  dentro de casillas disponibles hay una posicion que es ocupada

        if (casillasDisponibles[i] == guardarX[i]){ //si la posicion disponible es 0 y hay un 0 en el array de x
            alert("La posición de la casilla disponible es igual a la posición de la x puesta");
            casillasDisponibles[i].splice(i, "x", i); //insertamos la x para ocuparla
            if (n != guardarX[i] && n != 4){
                pintarO(n); 
            }
        } else {
            if (casillasDisponibles[n] != 4) {
                pintarO(n); 
            } //Si es igual a 4 el switch ejecutará otra vez esta función
        }
    }
}

function Gana(letra) { //A esta función le pasamos la letra O o X para saber quien ha ganado
    //creamos un nuevo array(map) con los resultados de la llamada a la función indicada aplicados a cada uno de sus elementos 
    let checks = casillasInterno.relleno.map(pos => pos.value === letra);
    /*Función de flecha: ej: yo hago click en una posición marcando x
    entonces, esta función retornaria falso porque estoy comparando la x con
    la o de la maquina que es la letra, esto lo hace leyendo todas las casillas que hay*/
    
    //Recorremos las filas 
    // La i esta puesta de 3 en 3 porque la recorremos de fila 1-2-3
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
        //Si casilla[0]  && casilla[i(0) + 1] && casilla[i(0) + 2] Fila 1 (posiciones 0-1-2)
        //Si casilla[3]  && casilla[i(3) + 1] && casilla[i(3) + 2] Fila 2 (posiciones 3-4-5)
        //Si casilla[6]  && casilla[i(6) + 1] && casilla[i(6) + 2] Fila 3 (posiciones 6-7-8)
        //i = 9 ¿9 < 9? -> se sale del bucle y comprueba las demás
        if (checks[i] && checks[i + 1] && checks[i + 2]){
            return true;
        }   
    }

    //Recorremos las columnas
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (checks[i] && checks[i + 3] && checks[i + 6]){
            return true;  
        }       
    }

    //Recorremos las diagonales
    if (checks[0] && checks[4] && checks[8]){
        return true;
    }
    
    if (checks[2] && checks[4] && checks[6]){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function condicionesGanaroPerder(){
    //Condiciones de ganar, perder o empate
    if (Gana("o")) {
        alert("La máquina ha ganado");
        
    } else if (Gana("x")) {
        alert("¡El jugador ha ganado!");

    } else if (casillasInterno.relleno.every(casilla => casilla !== "v"))  {
        //El every le pregunta a la función en flecha(necesaria) si los valores del array casilla no son iguales a -
        //en el caso de que no hayan - y que el array este completo, el every dira que es verdadero(true) y alertara de que hay un empate
        //en el caso de que sea falso pasará al siguiente else
        alert("Empate");
    } else {
        //Aún no gana
        pintaMaquina();
        if (Gana("o")) {
            alert("La máquina ha ganado");
        }
    }
}
//Si se le ha dado click al boton enviar eliminamos el numero de click guardado en el array
boton.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    guardarClicks.splice(0, guardarClicks.length);
}, false);

//Si hacemos click en la casilla, en el primer array se guarda el valor de x en cada casilla
function clickCasilla(i) {
    var contadorClicks = 0;
    contadorClicks++;
    guardarClicks.push(contadorClicks);
    guardarX.push(i); //Guardamos en que posición se ha puesto una x

    if (guardarClicks.length == 1){
    
        if (casillasInterno.relleno[i] == "v"){
            casillasInterno.relleno.splice(i, 0,"x"); //Ponemos una x en la posición correspondiente
            ponerImagen(i,fotoX);
        }
    
    } else {
        alert("Sólo puedes poner 1 X");
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tres en raya</title>
    <style>
        table { 
            width: 20%;
        } 
        td { 
            border: 1px solid black;  
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #15C1A9;
            border-radius: 3%;
            justify-content: center;
        } 
        #boton {
           margin-left: 90px;
        }

        img {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .not-active {
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body onload="comienzaElJuego();">
  
    <form action="TresEnRayaFuncionamiento.js">
    <table id="tabla">
        <tbody>
           
            <tr> 
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla0" onclick="clickCasilla(0)"></td> 
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla1" onclick="clickCasilla(1)"></td>
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla2" onclick="clickCasilla(2)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla3" onclick="clickCasilla(3)"></td> 
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla4"></td>
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla5" onclick="clickCasilla(5)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla6" onclick="clickCasilla(6)"></td> 
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla7" onclick="clickCasilla(7)"></td>
                <td class="respuestas" id="casilla8" onclick="clickCasilla(8)"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="   Fin del turno  " id="boton"  onclick="condicionesGanaroPerder()"></input>
    <script src="TresEnRayaFuncionamiento.js"></script> <!-- Lo pongo aquí porque sino me da error el onclick -->

</body>
</html>
```

Probé a cambiar como estaba hecha la función pintaMaquina, porque las x me las cambiaba por las o, antes lo tenía puesto así:

```
function pintaMaquina(){
    maquina = "o";
    alert("Esta pintando la maquina...");

    var casillasDisponibles = []; //creamos un segundo array de las casillas disponibles

    for (let i = 0; i < casillas.length; i++){ //recorremos el primer array 
        
        if (casillas[i].value === "-"){//le decimos que si encuentra una - que la guarde en el segundo array según la posición
            casillasDisponibles.push(i);
        } 
            
    }

    var rng = Math.round(Math.random() * (casillasDisponibles.length - 1)); //calculamos numero random dentro de las casillas disponibles
    var numRandom = casillasDisponibles[rng];
    pintarO(numRandom); //Pasamos la posición libre para pintar la jugada de la máquina
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En programación algo estático "static" tiene una connotación, que pienso es distinto a lo que estas buscando.

El problema que yo veo es que tienes código que sobra y desordena el asunto. Guardas los clicks, no entiendo porque motivo.

Por ejemplo todo el manejo de imágenes que tienes:

```js
var imagenX = new Image();  //Creamos el objeto imagen
imagenX.src = "./img/x.png";    //Asociamos la ruta de la imagenX
fotoX = '<img src="'+imagenX.src+'" />';

var imagenR = new Image(); 
imagenR.src = "./img/_.png"; 
fotoR = '<img src="'+imagenR.src+'" />';


var imagenO = new Image(); 
imagenO.src = "./img/o.png"; 
fotoO = '<img src="'+imagenO.src+'" />';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
document.getElementById('casilla4').innerHTML += fotoO;

function ponerImagen(i,foto){
    switch (i) {
        case 0:  
            document.getElementById('casilla0').innerHTML = foto;
            break;
        
        case 1:
            document.getElementById('casilla1').innerHTML = foto; 
            break;

        case 2:
            document.getElementById('casilla2').innerHTML = foto; 
            break;

        case 3:
            document.getElementById('casilla3').innerHTML = foto; 
            break;

        case 4:
            pintaMaquina();
            break;

        case 5:
            document.getElementById('casilla5').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

        case 6:
            document.getElementById('casilla6').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

        case 7:
            document.getElementById('casilla7').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

        case 8:
            document.getElementById('casilla8').innerHTML = foto;  
            break;

    }
          
}
```

Se puede reemplazar por una función como esta:

```
function pintar(i, e) {
   document.getElementById('casilla' + i).innerHTML = GetImage(e);
 }
function GetImage(e) {
  return `./img/${e}.png"`;
}
```

También puedes poner una variable

```
let JuegaPersona = true;
```

Para saber si es verdadero es que juega la persona y si es falso juego el computador.

Para cambiar el valor solo haces

```
JuegaPersona = !JuegaPersona ;
```

Otro tips, es crear un diccionario con los valores

```
const Tipos = { x: "X", o: "O", v: " " };
```

Esto te permite cambiar el nombre de las imágenes sin necesidad de cambiar el código, solo lo cambias en el diccionario

Te dejo un código modificado del tuyo para que lo estudies.

```js
const casillasInterno = {
    relleno: []
};

const Tipos = { x: "X", o: "O", v: " " };

let JuegaPersona = true;

function GetImage(e) {
    return `./img/${e}.png`;
}


function pintar(i, e) {
    casillasInterno.relleno[i] = e;
    //document.getElementById('casilla' + i).innerHTML = GetImage(e);
    
    //Aquí ponemos una letra, solo con fines de testeo
    document.getElementById('casilla' + i).innerHTML = e;
}

function comienzaElJuego(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        if (i != 4) { 
            pintar(i, Tipos.v);
        }
        else {
            pintar(i, Tipos.o);
        }
    }
    JuegaPersona = true;
}

function Jugar(i, e) {
    pintar(i, e);
            
    if (Gana(e)) {
        Write("ha ganado: " + e);
    }
    else {
        let CasillasDisponible = GetCasillasDisponibles();
        if (CasillasDisponible.length > 0) {
            JuegaPersona = !JuegaPersona;
            if (!JuegaPersona) {
                juegaMaquina(CasillasDisponible);
            }
        }
        else {
            Write("Empate");
        }
                
    }

}

function random(hasta) {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * hasta);
    return num;
}

function GetCasillasDisponibles() {
    return casillasInterno.relleno.map((a, i) => { return { index: i, valor: a } }).filter(a => a.valor == Tipos.v);
}
function juegaMaquina(disponibles){
    let pos = random(disponibles.length);
    Jugar(disponibles[pos].index, Tipos.o);
}

function Gana(letra)
{ 
    let checks = casillasInterno.relleno.map(pos => pos === letra);
            
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
        if (checks[i] && checks[i + 1] && checks[i + 2]){
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Recorremos las columnas
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (checks[i] && checks[i + 3] && checks[i + 6]){
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Recorremos las diagonales
    if (checks[0] && checks[4] && checks[8]){
        return true;
    }

    if (checks[2] && checks[4] && checks[6]){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}



function clickCasilla(i)
{
    if (JuegaPersona) {
        Jugar(i, Tipos.x);
    }
    else
    {
        Write("Sólo puedes poner 1 X");
    }

}
function Write(mensaje) {
    document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = mensaje;
}
comienzaElJuego();
```

```css
table {
            width: 20%;
        }
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: #15C1A9;
            border-radius: 3%;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 20px
        }
        #boton {
           margin-left: 90px;
        }

        img {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .not-active {
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }
```

```html
<table id="tabla">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla0" onclick="clickCasilla(0)"></td>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla1" onclick="clickCasilla(1)"></td>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla2" onclick="clickCasilla(2)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla3" onclick="clickCasilla(3)"></td>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla4"></td>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla5" onclick="clickCasilla(5)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla6" onclick="clickCasilla(6)"></td>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla7" onclick="clickCasilla(7)"></td>
            <td class="respuestas" id="casilla8" onclick="clickCasilla(8)"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="mensaje"></div>
<button onclick="comienzaElJuego()">Comenzar</button>
```

La lógica la tiene la función "jugar" la cual marca la casilla, verifica si existen casillas disponibles, verifica si se ganó y determina quien juega.

Y el órden de ejecución es:

- comienzaElJuego
- clickCasilla
- Jugar
- juegaMaquina
- Jugar
- clickCasilla
- Jugar
- juegaMaquina
- y así hasta que se gana, pierde o empata

Comment: Muchas gracias  @Yussef ! :) estaba muy perdida, respecto a cómo pones las imágenes aún no hemos dado la librería JQuery, pero he reciclado tu forma de hacerlo ya que esta super optimizada y la he dejado así:                                                                              `function GetImage(e) {                              
    if (e == "O") {
        return '<img src="'+imagenO.src+'" />';
    } else if (e == "X"){
        return '<img src="'+imagenX.src+'" />';
    } else if (e == " ") {
        return '<img src="'+imagenR.src+'" />';
    }
}` Muchas gracias otra vez!!

Comment: Que bueno te haya servidor. Pero debo aclarar que yo no ocupe jQuery y si te refieres a esta parte `./img/${e}.png`. Esto es se llama "Template literal" (Buscalo en google porque es muy útil) y es parte de javascript. Esto te permite concatenar texto de manera fácil y es lo mismo que poner "./img/"+ e +".png"